# How to flash locally built aosp OS(built in local system) to raspberry pi/any embedded hardware

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, embedded, android-source, android-build

I am writing this  question after searching a lot in google, there was no complete guide in how to flash android os on a embedded hardware.

What i am trying to do,
Build aosp with some modifications and i want to flash this into an embedded hardware like raspberry pi. So wanted to know what are all the steps to be followed for achieving the same.

Not able to understand this flow. I am a newbie to embedded world so kindly excuse me if my motive/understanding is wrong.

Comment: You perhaps need to find a Q&A on effective searching.  Have you not found yourself here: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewforum.php?f=56&sid=b0080fb08618366eede35fefd1864a97 yet?  You cannot of course "flash" an RPi - they boot from SD card.

Comment: I know that in pi we cant flash, but for pi we have to put os in a memory card and on booting pi it would start the OS. My main motive was to understand the entire flashing process. Eg: along with system image(android) what other contents is required. Might be you did not understand my motive. Anyways thanks for your comment.

Comment: I understood you perfectly.  I was simply commenting on _you_ referring to flashing an RPi.  The process is I would guess not Android specific, but platform specific. Android is not that common an OS on embedded outside of a few large manufacturers building thier own hardware.  Your question relating to "embedded hardware like..." is too non specific.  Each platform will differ.  Hence me directing you to the specific RPi forum.

Comment: Further resource: https://emteria.com/blog/android-on-raspberry-pi.  It was easy to find, so perhaps you are looking for something else?  Perhaps you need to explain what you need that is not provided by this, but questions about finding  resources or documentation are off topic here - hence posting a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Yes i was not specific bcz i wanted to know whether there is a generic approach to all hardwares. And secondly if u run an aosp build then 5 different img's get generated(system.img, cache.img, ramdisk.img, vendor.img, userdata.img) and i was not able to understand the purpose of these easily and also to deploy to hardware it was stated that we need a hardware specific kernel then hal implementations and finally these images. So that is why i wanted to know whether there is a generic way to all hardwares(like writing a generic algo). But now i understand my assumption was wrong.

Comment: You were specific in the title, not generic at all.